# "no such file or directory, sml" in emacs

Tags: emacs

I installed `emacs 24.3` and SML-MODE. When I open a `.sml` file in `emacs` and try to run buffer using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> it gives:

```
Searching for program: no such file or directory
```

sml emacs is extracted at /etc/emacs-24.3 and sml is extracted at /home/user/softwares

Also I am unable to run sml from terminal. I think I have to add the path of SML to emacs somehow.

Is that right? or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, customize user option (variable) `exec-path`: `C-h v exec-path`.
See also the Emacs manual, node `Shell`: `C-h r g Shell`.